# jQuery Mobile Dialog box appears then disappears in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have my index file as a dialog box for users to enter a username and password. The page works fine when it is a `data-role="page` but as a dialog the dialog shows and quickly disappears. It basically flashes onto the screen and I have no idea why. My code is below:

HTML

```
<body onload="init()">

<div id="home">

    <div id="launcherPage" data-role="page">
        <!-- I'm just here waiting for deviceReady -->
    </div>


    <div data-role="dialog" id="loginPage">

        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>CHUNE</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">    

            <form id="loginForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
            </form>
            <div style="text-align: center;">Or</div> <!--need to center-->
            <a href="./register.html" data-role="button">Register</a>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&copy; KewsPlus</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
```

jQuery

```
function deviceReady() {
console.log("deviceReady");
$("#loginPage").on("pageinit",function() {
    console.log("pageinit run");
    $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);
    checkPreAuth();
});
$.mobile.changePage("#loginPage");
```

Comment: You call it once the app is initiated?

Comment: No it is called as a normal page the index.html page itself is a dialog itself

Comment: Then it should have `data-role=dialog` not page.

Comment: The data role is set to dialog in my code

Comment: The file index.html is itself a dialog there is no data role of page on it.

Comment: Oh ok, `$.mobile.changePage('index.html', { role:'dialog'});`

Answer (score 1):

To open a dialog programmatically on load, you need to set a timeout to insure that pages are completely loaded into DOM before opening it.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#myPage' ,function () {
 setTimeout(function () {
  $.mobile.changePage('#dialog');
 }, 100); // delay above zero
});
```

> **[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692186/jquery-mobile-dialog-on-page-load)**

Comment: That's strange as I have another dialog that works fine when I call it normally will share that code also

Comment: Dialogs are placed out of page div and have data role dialog.

Comment: I tried this code and it works however the dialog still appears then disappears then reappears and stays now.

Comment: Have you used `setTimeout` with this `$.mobile.changePage('index.html', { 'role':'dialog'});` @KernElliott