# Why Does Opening A Dialog Too Early Fail w/ jQuery Mobile changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I am trying to open a dialog with JQM as soon as the page is loaded.  However calling changePage with data-role='dialog' too soon results in the dialog being shown and immediately closed.  When data-role='page' this does not occur.  Using a setTimeout method can work but requires large delays to ensure functionality across mobile devices/browsers.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#login",{role:'page'});
```

when role=page it stays open

```
$.mobile.changePage("#login",{role:'dialog'});
```

when role=dialog the dialog briefly flashes and then closes

```
setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.changePage("#login",{role:'dialog'});},2000);
```

usually works with long delay but undesirable

Please see demo: http://jsbin.com/eredac/2

Note: Issue not present in Firefox

**UPDATE:** Maybe it could also be resolved by doing the following:

Set autoInitializePage to false, get the url hash, set the active page to the dialog (default, first page), manually initialize, when the dialog is finished call changePage with the url hash as the destination?

Something like this:

http://jsbin.com/eredac/9

But dialog is shown without transition animation.  I prefer the other way but a >1s delay is not acceptable.  So if there is no way to trigger at the correct time I may settle for this.  Maybe try to at least fade in the dialog? (EDIT: Added the fade in.  Moderately satisfied with that result.)

Comment: Because you open it before the whole document is inserted into DOM. SetTimeout is the only possible solution for it. 100ms is enough usually, 2000ms is relatively long. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692186/jquery-mobile-dialog-on-page-load/15929161#15929161

Comment: Omar is right, 100 ms will be enough. This is a webkit problem also related to popups....

Comment: While small delays work on desktop browsers, 1000ms is not enough on iOS mobile safari launched as a homescreen app.  Dialog does not stay open.  If DOM is not fully loaded why does it render properly before closing (w/ transitions) and why does it stay open if changePage is called twice on the dialog?  I am not clear on exactly what is happening after the pageshow event returns.