# on loading the page a message should open in popup in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

on loading the page a message should open in popup in jquery mobile. is it possible. Am having the following code in which am using a button, on clicking that the popup is opening but i need it directly while after loading the page without clicking on anything. please someone help me thanks.

```
<div id="content-area">
        <div class="list_icon"><img src="images/reset.png" width="42" height="41"/></div>
                    <div class="list_head">Reset Progress</div>
                    <div class="list_reset">
                        <a href="#popupStatus" data-rel="popup"><img src="images/reset_btn.png" /></a>
                    </div>  
       <div data-role="popup" id="popupStatus" data-position-to="window" data-corners="true" >
                <div data-role="content">
                    <div class="ui-popup">Do you want to Reset the progress</div>
                    <br/>                       
                    <hr >
                    <div id="confirm_btn">
                        <div style="width:40%;float:left">
                            <a href="#" onClick="resetprogress();" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-theme="c">
                                Yes
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width:40%;float:right;">
                            <a href="#" class="ui-corner-all" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">
                                No
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: 1) popup div should be a direct child of `data-role=page`. 2) this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15929161/1771795

Comment: hi omar i gave as <script>
$( document ).bind("pageinit", function() {
  $("#popupStatus").show();
});

</script>
 but still it is showing nothing, is the div that am giving as popup is correct or not

Comment: which jqm version are you using?

Comment: jquery version  1.9.1

Comment: atleast please help me to create a popup dialogue box please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First off, `data-role="popup"` should be a direct *child* of `data-role="page"`. Don't place it inside any other div, otherwise, it won't fucntion/open properly.
- To open a popup or close it programmatically, use `.popup("open")` or `.popup("close")`.
- You can't call a *popup* on `pageshow` without a `setTimeout()`. You need to delay opening it to ensure that page has passed all events and is fully shown.
- **Update:** To close *popup* from a button, add `data-dismissible="false"` and `data-history="false"`  attributes to *popup* div. For closing button add `data-rel="back"`, or close it programmatically `.popup("close")`.

  ```
  $(document).on("pageshow", "#page_ID", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#popup_ID").popup("open");
    }, 100);
  });
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/M23kG/)**

Comment: hi omar it is working on clicking on the button but needed while loading the page itself

Comment: It works when change page, from main to next page. It doesn't open on click.

Comment: yes i have found that but for two pages am having seperate files, so there was some confusion

Comment: Are you using single page model? Multi html files?

Comment: hi omar can we remove scroll for this popup, and also, one more problem is clicking on anywhere on the page, the popup is closing. it should close only clicking on exact button, the popup is as follows <div class="ui-popup">Do you want Reset progress</div><hr ><div id="confirm_btn">     <div style="width:40%;float:left"><a href="#" onClick="resetprogress();" data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-theme="c">Yes</a></div><div style="width:40%;float:right;"><a href="#" class="ui-corner-all" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">No</div>

Comment: @user2419839 what do you mean by scroll? check updated answer.